# Apache CXF ExceptionMapper with request message

Tags: java, rest, exception, cxf

I was wondering if something like this is possible or if there's a better way to do it:

```
public class WebServiceExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {

  private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebServiceExceptionMapper.class);

  @Override
  public Response toResponse(Exception ex, Message requestMessage) {
    logger.error("request=" + httpMessage.etc..etc.., ex);
    return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
  }

}
```

Basically I would like to be able to log not just the exception but the request message that triggered the error. More specifically if the request contains a JSON or XML I would like to grab that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM. Figured it out by injecting MessageContext in my ExceptionMapper and adding a custom RequestHandler like described here: http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/Accessing-JAXRS-JSON-content-directly-td4390185.html

```
public class StringContentRequestHandler implements RequestHandler { 

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RawContentRequestHandler.class); 

public Response handleRequest(Message m, ClassResourceInfo resourceClass) { 
    InputStream is = m.getContent(InputStream.class); 
    try { 
        CachedOutputStream bos = new CachedOutputStream(); 
        IOUtils.copy(is, bos); 

        bos.flush(); 
        is.close(); 

        m.setContent(InputStream.class, bos.getInputStream()); 
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
        bos.writeCacheTo(builder, "utf-8"); 
        m.setContent(String.class, builder.toString()); 
        return null; 

    } catch (IOException ex) { 
        logger.error("IOException on getting raw content", ex); 
        return null; 
    } 
} 
}
```